# Adding 2nd level variable into Multi-level Modelling in R

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

I have a dataset (`data.mrsa`) about the MRSA prevalence of elderly in long term care facilities (LTCF) with the following information:

- mrsa_result: MRSA result of recruited elderly (positive VS negative)
- age: residents' age
- ltcf: UID for each LTCF (we sampled 30 out of 1000 LTCFs)
- ltcf_type: type of LTCF (private VS non-private)

I have a multi-level logistic regression model like the one below:

```
fit2 <- glmer(mrsa_result ~ age + (1|ltcf), family=binomial("logit"),data=data.mrsa)
```

I know I am trying to find out the effect of `age` on the log-odds of `mrsa_result`, having the `ltcf` on the 2nd level gives me a wider CI on the lod-odds.

Now I want to add the `ltcf_type` into the model, I think this should be a fixed effect, as there can only be private and non-private, but `itcf_type` should be considered as 2nd level data, right? As this describe the type of LTCF, not the type of elderly.

I am puzzled on where should I put the term `ltcf_type` into my model, I wonder which of the following lines is correct:

```
fit2a <- glmer(mrsa_result ~ age + ltcf_type + (1|ltcf), family=binomial("logit"),data=data.mrsa)
fit2b <- glmer(mrsa_result ~ age + (1|ltcf + ltcf_type), family=binomial("logit"),data=data.mrsa)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> fit2a <- glmer(mrsa_result ~ age + ltcf_type + (1|ltcf), family=binomial("logit"),data=data.mrsa)

The first line is correct. Each unit on L2 is represented in multiple data rows, and lme4 recognizes that ltcf_type is constant for each entry within a L2 unit. So it is treated automatically as a fixed effect on L2.